# Chrome inline installations. Do the installations from my website get counted in chrome webstore installs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

We have included chrome inline installation on our website http://compare.buyhatke.com/
But we feel that the installations from the page are not getting counted in the chromestore. We are tracking the installations from this page [compare.buyhatke.com/extension.php](http://compare.buyhatke.com/extension.php) which takes the user to a thank you page. And the analytics everyday is showing upto 100-150 installations.

But the chrome webstore dashboard only shows 15-20 installations. Which may be happening from the chromestore itself.

Are the values shown on the chrome webstore dashboard of the installations inclusive of the uninstallations. Also how can we track uninstallations of the extension ?

Comment: On http://compare.buyhatke.com/success.php and http://compare.buyhatke.com/thankYou.php, are you setting a cookie to distinguish repeat visits to those pages from the same user? I didn't see any; moreover, your Cache-Control headers seem to be designed to cause unnecessary refetches and thus duplicate counts. This might not be the actual problem, but I don't see any defensive measures in your code that would narrow down the cause.

Comment: Hey Kay,   Gooogle analytics does show repeat, new and unique visitors in the panel. So we know how many unique visitors came to the site via that.

Comment: Shame this question never got an answer..